# Coloring nodes in d3 v5 based on degree of nodes

Tags: html, css, json, d3.js

In d3 v5, how would you color a node based on degree of the nodes. It must be visually evident that the nodes with a higher degree use darker/deeper colors and the nodes with lower degrees use lighter colors.

I added the following, but didn't seem to work

```
// define a color scale that maps node degree to a color
var colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
.domain(\[1, 5\]) // node degree range
.range(\["#fbb4ae", "#b3cde3", "#ccebc5", "#decbe4", "#fed9a6"\]); // color range

// create a node selection and bind data`
var node = svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "nodes")
.selectAll("circle")
.data(nodes)
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("r", 5)
.style("fill", function(d) { return colorScale(d.degree); }); 
// use the color scale to color     the nodes
```

Comment: What is this `.domain(\[1, 5\])`? What are you escaping? It should be `.domain([1, 5])`.

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
```

```js
// define a color scale that maps node degree to a color

let nodes= [{degree:1},{degree:4},{degree:10},{degree:16},{degree:1}]
let value =nodes.map((el) => el.degree);
let DOMAIN= [d3.min(value),d3.max(value)]
let colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
.domain( DOMAIN) // node degree range
.range(["#fbb4ae", "#b3cde3", "#ccebc5", "#decbe4", "#fed9a6"]); // color range

let radiusScale = d3.scaleLinear()
.domain( DOMAIN) // node degree range
.range([5,10]);
// create a node selection and bind data`
let svgContainer = d3.select('#svg').append('svg').attr('width',200).attr('height',200);
svgContainer.selectAll('circle').data(nodes).enter().append('circle').attr('r',(d,i) => radiusScale (d.degree)).attr('cy',10).attr('cx',(d,i) => i*30+5).attr('fill',(d,i) => colorScale(d.degree))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id='svg'></div>
```